# error connecting to master 'replica@192.168.57.10:3306' mac-ubuntu

Tags: mysql, replication, ubuntu, mac-os-x, vmware

**Server info:**

```
Master server (Vmware): Ubuntu 18.04    IP: 192.168.57.10
Slave server1 (Vmware): Ubuntu 18.04    IP: 192.168.57.11
Slave server2 (mac): macOS High Sierra  IP: 192.168.0.3
```

**MySQL Server version:**

```
Mac: 5.7.23-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Ubuntu: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log (Ubuntu)
```

**Server status:**

```
1) Ping between all these three servers works
Result: works

2) ssh loging between all these three servers works
Result: works

3) netcat -vv 192.168.0.3 3306     # connecting from 192.168.57.10 and 192.168.57.11
Result: Connection to 192.168.0.3 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!

4) mysql -p -h 192.168.0.3         # connecting from 192.168.57.10 and 192.168.57.11
Result: works

5) Info: using mysql_native_password

6) 
Master server: bind-address = 192.168.57.10
Slave server1: bind-address = 192.168.57.11
Slave server2: bind-address = 192.168.0.3 (tried with * also)

7) Master to slave server 1
mysql> show slave status\G
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.57.10
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000072
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 154
               Relay_Log_File: xxx-serverb-relay-bin.000088
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000072
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
....
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 

Result: works
Info: Master-Ubuntu <-> Slave-Ubuntu

8) Master to slave server 2
mysql> show slave status\G
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 192.168.57.10
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000068
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 154
               Relay_Log_File: xxx-iMac-relay-bin.000003
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000068
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
....
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1045
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replica@192.168.57.10:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 28
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 

Result: Not working
Info: Master-Ubuntu <-> Slave-Mac
```

**MySQL user details:**

```
mysql> SHOW grants for replica@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replica@%                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replica'@'%' |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW grants for replica@'192.168.0.3';
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replica@192.168.0.3                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replica'@'192.168.0.3' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW grants for replica@'192.168.57.11';
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replica@192.168.57.11                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replica'@'192.168.57.11' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 1045 is an access denied error.

I advise verify if you have granted privileges to the master user in the mac OSX mysql service.

Comment: I changed the privileges to "All Privileges". Still not connecting.